# can't access administration page in Glassfish 4 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish-4

I have a Glassfish 4 server on Ubuntu 14 virtualBox.

This virtual machine has 2 network interfaces. From the host machine (Windows 7) I can't access the Glassfish administration page, although I have enabled secure administration in the server.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Any details about the actual problem would be helpful. How have you configured the network interfaces, can you ping the vm, can you reach the login page, how are you accessing the admin page and so on...

Comment: Ok , one interface is NAT , the other is Host only , both interfaces are pingable from the host machine .. the web admin page is accessible from locally only localhost:4848 , but it cant be accessible through the machine's IP 10.0.2.15:4848.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the IP of your NAT interface to reach the server. This is not possible. You have to use the IP of the Host-Only interface.

To get the IP, start a terminal and run `ifconfig`. It should display 3 interfaces: `eth0`, `eth1` and `lo`. Take the IP which is not 10.0.2.15 (probably something like 192.168.56.x if you didn't change the settings for the Host-Only interface) and it should work.

Comment: it's working now, the problem that i'm behind a proxy server , so when i disabled the proxy , i'm was able to connect .. Thanks